Non-Euclidean projections
Background
Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be a given point and let $V_1,V_2\in\mathbb{R^2}$ be the vertices of a given segment. Define the projection of $y$ over the segment $s=(V_1,V_2)$ as
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{proj}_s(y)\triangleq \arg \min_{p\in s} \lVert y-p\rVert
\end{equation*}
In words, $\mathrm{proj}_s(y)$ is the point $p$ belonging to $s$ that is closest to $y$ in the sens of the Euclidean norm. Is not that difficult to show that
\begin{equation}
\tag{*}
\mathrm{proj}_s(y)= \begin{cases} 
\hfil V_1 \hfil & \text{if } \lambda < 0 \\
\hfil V_2 \hfil & \text{if } \lambda > 1 \\
\hfil (1-\lambda)V_1+\lambda V_2 \hfil & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\tag{**}
\lambda = \frac{(y-V_1)'(V_2-V_1)}{(V_2-V_1)'(V_2-V_1)}
\end{equation}
proof
For the sake of brevity, let's call $y^*\triangleq \mathrm{proj}_s(y)$. By definition, $y^*$ belongs to $s$, which means that it can be written in the following form
\begin{equation*}
y^* = (1-\lambda)V_1+\lambda V_2
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda$ is a suitable scalar ranging in the normalized interval $[0, 1]$. To find the value of $\lambda$, note that $y^*$ is the point in $s$ such that $y-y^*$ is orthogonal to $V_2-V_1$. Hence, we are searching for $\lambda$ such that
\begin{equation*}
(y-y^*)'(V_2-V_1)=0 \qquad \equiv \qquad 
\{y-[(1-\lambda)V_1 + \lambda V_2]\}'(V_2-V_1)=0
\end{equation*}
which is solved by $(**)$. Now, $(**)$ can map $y^*$ outside $s$ if the returned value is not in the range $[0,1]$. In that case, we can saturate the returned value to $0$ or $1$ to make sure that $y^*=(1-\lambda)V_1+\lambda V_2$ is a point on the segment.
\begin{equation}\blacksquare\end{equation}
Question
Can we generalize this simple result to the more one where the Euclidean norm $\lVert x\lVert$ is replaced by $\lVert x \rVert_{M}\triangleq \sqrt{x'M x}$ where $M$ is a symmetric and positive definite matrix? In particular, I'm wondering if $(*)$ still holds with the new convention
\begin{equation}
\lambda = \frac{(y-V_1)' M (V_2-V_1)}{(V_2-V_1)' M (V_2-V_1)}
\end{equation}
EDIT
I've made a partial progess. Firstly, it is convenient to consider the squared distance
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{proj}_s(y)\triangleq \arg \min_{p\in s} \lVert p-y\rVert_M=
\arg \min_{p\in s} \lVert p-y\rVert_M^2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
then, as $p\in s$, the projection can be written as
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{proj}_s(y)=(1-\lambda^*)V_1+\lambda^*V_2
\end{equation*}
for some suitable $\lambda^* \in [0,1]$ given by
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\lambda^*=
\arg \min_{\lambda\in [0,1]} \lVert (1-\lambda)V_1+\lambda V_2 -y\rVert_M^2=\arg \min_{\lambda\in [0,1]} \lVert \underbrace{(V_2-V_1)}_{\triangleq A}\lambda + \underbrace{V_1 -y}_{\triangleq B}\rVert_M^2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Now note that, by completing the square, holds
\begin{equation*}
\lVert A\lambda + B \rVert_M^2 = \frac{1}{(A'MA)^{-1}}\left(\lambda+\frac{B'MA}{A'MA}\right)^2+\text{something independent from $\lambda$}
\end{equation*}
which, as $A'MA>0$, is minimized by
\begin{equation}
\lambda^\star \triangleq -\frac{B'MA}{A'MA}= \frac{(y-V_1)M(V_2-V_1)}{(V2-V_1)M(V_2-V_1)}
\end{equation}
in general, this is not the searched solution because the box constraint $\lambda^\star \in [0,1]$ is not guaranteed. Let's say that the solution is
\begin{equation}
\tag{*}
\lambda^*= \begin{cases} 
\hfil 0 \hfil & \text{if } \lambda^\star < 0 \\
\hfil 1 \hfil & \text{if } \lambda^\star > 1 \\
\hfil  \lambda^\star
 \hfil & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
If I'm not wrong, to prove the optimality of $\lambda^*$ we must check that the gradient in $\lambda=1$ is positive and in $\lambda=0$ is negative. We have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\lVert A\lambda+B\rVert_M^2}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}
=\begin{cases}
B'MA     & \text{if } \lambda=0 \\
A'MA+B'MA & \text{if } \lambda=1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and this point I got stuck. Problably in the first case I have also to consider $\lambda^\star<0$ and in the second case $\lambda^\star>0$.
